# JqueryUI Draggable clone image replace src

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I create functions based on https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

I have a problem with the replacement src cloned item.
If I drag the item to a sortable list (cloned). I can't replace the src of the cloned item. Src conversion work normally for all other items on the list.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Drag and replace photo</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        li {
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 230px;
        }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <ul>
                    <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Jupiter.jpg"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <ul id="sortable">

                    <li class="ui-state-default"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"></li>

                </ul>
            </div>



    </body>

</html>
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    $("ul, li").disableSelection();

    $("img").click(function() {
        ivo = $(this).attr('src')
        console.log(ivo)

        $(this).attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Zeta_Puppis.png');

    });
});
```

Comment: I would think this would be done in the `drop` or `drag`. What have you tried?

Comment: Tested your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/n43fqv54/ and I do not see what you're trying to adjust. Are you replacing a current `li` or adding the new `li` to your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a second, but I think the issue is with the dynamically created `img`. Instead of using `.click()`, you will want to use `.on('click', function(){});` so that the function will be applied on the click event of any new created images as well as those that exist in the DOM at page load.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/n43fqv54/2/

I found I needed to apply the event binding to the cloned `img` inside the `li`, so instead of raw cloning the via `helper`, I created a `function()` to handle this.

**JQuery**

```
function srcSwap(target) {
  var ivo = target.attr("src");
  console.log(ivo);
  target.attr("src", 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Zeta_Puppis.png');
}

$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
  });

  $("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: function(e) {
      var $c = $(e.target).parent().clone();
      $c.find("img").on("click", function() {
        srcSwap($(this));
      });
      return $c;
    },
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $("ul, li").disableSelection();

  $(".img-responsive").on("click", function() {
    srcSwap($(this));
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent solution and a great explanation of the code.